# FLASK in Python - Videos won't play on chrome oder edge but play perfectly in firefox and safari

Tags: python, html, flask, video, mp4

i have a strange problem.
I made a page that should display videos from my local pc with a tunnel.

Thats my video player:

```
    <div class="container mx-auto text-center">
        <h4 class="text-center my-4">{{ title }}</h4>
        <div class="video-container">
            <video id="video-player" controls preload="auto" playsinline>
                <source src="{{ url_for('stream_video', filename=video) }}" type="video/mp4">
                Ihr Browser unterstützt das Video-Tag nicht.
            </video>
            <p class="mt-3">{{ description }}</p>
        </div>
    </div><br><br>



    <a style="margin-left:15px" href="{{ url_for('index') }}" class="btn btn-red">Zurück zur Liste</a>
    <button style="margin-left:15px" id="stream-button" class="btn btn-ylw">Stream</button>
    <br><br><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("stream-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
            var videoPath = "{{ url_for('stream_video', filename=video) }}";

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/send_video_path", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ videoPath: videoPath }));
        });
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

thats my video details page (app.py):

```
@app.route('/video-detail/<filename>')
@login_required
def video_detail(filename):
    video_path = os.path.join(VIDEO_DIRECTORY, filename)
    if not os.path.exists(video_path):
        return "Video nicht gefunden", 404
    
    base_name = filename.split('.')[0]
    image_file = base_name + '.png'
    description_file = base_name + '.txt'
    image_path = os.path.join(VIDEO_DIRECTORY, image_file)
    description_path = os.path.join(VIDEO_DIRECTORY, description_file)

    image_url = url_for('send_image', filename=image_file) if os.path.exists(image_path) else url_for('send_image', filename='default-image.png')
    description = read_description(description_path)

    return render_template('video_detail.html', video=filename, image=image_url, title=base_name, description=description)
```

and the video stream route:

> @app.route('/video/')
> @login_required
> def stream_video(filename):
> video_path = os.path.join(VIDEO_DIRECTORY, filename)
>
> if not os.path.exists(video_path):
> return "Video nicht gefunden", 404
>
> video_size = os.path.getsize(video_path)
> range_header = request.headers.get('Range', None)
> byte1, byte2 = 0, video_size - 1
>
> if range_header:
> match = re.search('bytes=(\d+)-(\d*)', range_header)
> if match:
> groups = match.groups()
> if groups[0]:
> byte1 = int(groups[0])
> if groups[1]:
> byte2 = min(int(groups[1]), byte2)  # Vergewissern Sie sich, dass das Ende nicht über die Dateigröße hinaus geht
>
> length = byte2 - byte1 + 1
> data = None
> with open(video_path, 'rb') as f:
> f.seek(byte1)
> data = f.read(length)
>
> rv = Response(data, 206, mimetype='video/mp4', content_type='video/mp4', direct_passthrough=True)
> rv.headers.add('Content-Range', f'bytes {byte1}-{byte2}/{video_size}')
> rv.headers.add('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')
> rv.headers.add('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
>
> return rv

The very strange thing:
All videos work on firefox perfectly, also on my iphone (safari).
Some videos work on chrome and edge but the most not.

Does anyone know why? I'm stuck like a whole day in this problem and i dont know what the reason could be.

i tried to run it on localhost but its the same issue, ive tried to bind in video players but still same issue.

Comment: ok ive just seen, the videos load in edge and chrome but it takes a very long time and in firefox its happening directly. anyone any idea? thank you! also all videos are in the same video codec h.264

Comment: Your MP4 has the metadata (called MOOV section) at the back of the file. So it must fully download first before any playback. Use a tool like FFmpeg (if you know it) or look on Google search for `mp4 fast start` or `mp4 fix moov`. The solution is to move your MOOV section to the front of MP4.